# How to add unique constraint in firebase firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an Android application for mobile in which it takes the 'Roll number' from each user. That should be unique for each user. Firebase Firestore doesn't provide the unique constraint for particular field. So how can I add the unique constraint on 'Roll number' field. Is there any security rules?

Comment: what have you tried so far. can you share some code?

Comment: What is the exact constraint that you want to add? Please responde with @.

Comment: Maybe you can find something useful here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47405774/cloud-firestore-enforcing-unique-user-names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47405774/cloud-firestore-enforcing-unique-user-names).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloud Firestore: Enforcing Unique User Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47405774/cloud-firestore-enforcing-unique-user-names)

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box but you can achieve that creating a separate collection to index the unique field and adding a constraint in your security rules.

Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59892127/715451) which does the trick by using batched writes (which I think is more robust) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53032126/715451) which use triggers to update the index.